# What is Interaction class?

Tags: vb.net

I have two following rows of code:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Beep()
or
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Beep()
```

The result is the same in this two rows.

what is Interaction class?And when shold i use it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two lines result in exactly the same code being generated.  Which one you choose is a matter of style. Personally I would choose to simply use the `Beep()` command in the abscence of a namespace qualifier

```
Sub Main()
  Beep()
End Sub
```

Between the two choices you presented though I would choose `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Beep()` over `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Beep()`.  The former is the fully qualified name of the method and it's completely unambiguous to the reader.  The latter though is using a trick of VB.Net name resolution and one that would likely fool even the experienced VB.Net user.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best things I love about Visual Basic is that it makes the code easier and usually contains shortcuts to functions commonly used, such as `MsgBox`, `Stop` and `Beep`. That's why both lines yield the same result, because they are actually the same.

Also, as @JaredPar mentions, is better to either use fully qualified name `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Beep()` or just `Beep()` this will make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of an odd-duck name and have no good guess beyond the methods being available in the Immediate window.  The key is that the class is decorated with the `<StandardModule>` attribute.  Which is a hint to the compiler to move the members of class into the global name space.  So you can simply write MsgBox() and not bother with the class name.

Just like you could in VB6.